# Flutter on-screen keyboard creates whitespace when in use

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Soft keyboard alters my UI and prevents UI widgets from functioning properly while it is active.

Q: What is causing this issue? and how can it be properly fixed?

PS. I've tried SingleChildScrollView but I think it's not the solution.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber.shade50,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Biography', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ProfileEditor(),
    );
  }
}


class ProfileEditor extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
            child: Text('Tell something about yourself', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 300,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusColor: Colors.white,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9t7g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under your `Scaffold` Widget add those two properties:

```
//those will prevent your soft keyboard from altering your UI
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my previous solution! Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found out that adding the following code to your scaffold below will fix the solution.

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```